# Datatable filters not working after primefaces upgrade 8

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

Upgraded application from primefaces 5.3.6 to 8 version.Filters stop working in below data table.I didn't get any error in console.Looks like filters are not responding.Sorting working fine.

XHTML

```
<p:dataTable id="tableId1" var="v" paginator="true" value="dataModel"
    rowKey="rowKey" selectionMode="single" rowIndexVar="rowIndexVar"
    selection="selectedObj" widgetVar="wVar" filteredValue = "filteredResults"
    lazy = "lazyLoadIndicator" filterDelay="1000">
        <p:columns id="columnsId" value="#{columnsList}" var="column" sortBy="#{v[column.property1]}" filterBy="#{v[column.property1]}"
        filterMatchMode="contains">
        </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Java code:

```
private List<Model1> columnsList = new ArrayList<Model1>();
    
public class Model1 implements Serializable {
    private String property1;
     
    public Model1(String property) {
        this.property1 = property;  
    }
    
    public String getProperty1() {  
       return property1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the migration guide? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: And please split xhtml and java code in a question. And **try** to create a [mcve]

Comment: Your issue is right here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6171

Comment: @Melloware  For me adding  field="#{column.property1}" filtering not working.

Comment: I would follow the showcase example which is working: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml

Comment: @Melloware Showcase is not updated with field attribute on p:columns if filterBy is used

Comment: No its not but that showcase example works right? its sorts and filters are working or not for you?